# CIDv1 base32 encoding

Tags: ipfs, base32

Can anyone help me understand how string version is calculated for CIDv1?

Example:
bafykbzacea6h5nvlblvak5jhj7m7ku5sp7u2roo3lbembab3a6tnvmuzgcqas

Is this right hex representation according to CID [explorer](https://cid.ipfs.tech/#bafykbzacea6h5nvlblvak5jhj7m7ku5sp7u2roo3lbembab3a6tnvmuzgcqas)
0170B220203C7EB6AB0AEA0575274FD9F553B27FE9A8B9DB5848C0803B07A6DAB29930A009

Using this [tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_encode.html), values doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

The hex displayed by the CID explorer shows the HEX of the hash DIGEST part, not the entire CID. This enables you to extract raw `blake2b-256` from the CID.

CIDv1 have a prefix which for your CID is:

- multibase-indicator: `b` (base23) (which informs how to decode binary bytes that follow)
- cid version: `1`
- multicodec-content-type: `dag-pb`
- multihash, which itself has three fields

  - code of the hash function used: `blake2b-256`
  - length of digest: `32`
  - DIGEST

Relevant docs:

- https://github.com/multiformats/cid#how-does-it-work
- https://github.com/multiformats/multihash
- https://github.com/multiformats/multicodec/blob/master/table.csv → "code" column lists numeric value (in hex) for names like `dag-pb` etc

To inspect CID details like prefix (things before hash digest) with `ipfs cid format` (from [Kubo](https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/command-line-quick-start/)):

```
$ ipfs cid format -f "(%b)-(%v)-(%c)-(%h)-(%L)-DIGEST" bafykbzacea6h5nvlblvak5jhj7m7ku5sp7u2roo3lbembab3a6tnvmuzgcqas
(base32)-(cidv1)-(dag-pb)-(blake2b-256)-(32)-DIGEST
```

See `ipfs cid format --help`.